# Survey data question

Tags: survey

I am a newbie!  I used a survey platform to collect responses on three different measures (15 childhood adversity yes/no questions,  10 resiliency 5pt Likert questions, and 20 5 point Likert stress questions).
I also collected age bands, years of service, and grade level taught (elementary or secondary).
I want to analyze this data to see if:
The yes questions on the first survey correlate to questions on the resilience and stress scale where participants indicated a 4 or 5.
I also want to use the demographics (age, service, level) to see the trends.
Any advice welcomed.

Comment: Do you intend to use each question within each domain separately or do you intend to try to aggregate them in some way to form a scale? Are you only interested in people who score 4 or 5 or do you mean to contrast them with people who scored 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: I would like to aggregate them to form a scale (separately) Ex:  Score on childhood adversity is one variable to then compare to the same participants aggregate score on resilience and stress.   I am only interested in people who score a 3 or more on adversity and who have low scores on the resilience and stress.